# PostgreSQL query for inserting new values to first_name and last_name of users table

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgres. I have a created a PostgreSQL query that I want to insert values for first_name and last_name for an existing record. The existing record can be found using id:

```
INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name)
VALUES ("John","Smith") 
WHERE id=100;
```

This give me syntax error at or near "WHERE".

I am not sure if my query is correct or not, but what is the possible best way to do this?

Comment: Why is this tagged ruby-on-rails? In Rails you would not write the SQL query from scratch in the first place as the ORM handles it. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update

Answer (score 2):

use **UPDATE** not **INSERT**, since you are updating the existing record.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1,
    column2 = value2,
    ...
WHERE condition
RETURNING * | output_expression AS output_name;
```

Your query will be something like this:

```
UPDATE users
SET first_name = 'John'
SET last_name = 'Smith'
WHERE id=100;
```